# Nestjs:validate function not working with jwt

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, nestjs

I'm trying to use jwt in nest following [document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEi0O.png)

Everything is ok, but validate function is not working in jwt.strategy.ts

this is my jwt.strategy.ts:

```js
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtPayload } from './interfaces/jwt-payload.interface';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT'),
      secretOrKey: 'secretKey',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
    console.log(payload)
    // const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
    // if (!user) {
    //   throw new UnauthorizedException();
    // }
    // return user;
  }
}
```

auth.module.ts:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: 'secretKey',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

app.module.ts:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When i request in postman, I don't got any log, It doesn't seem to enter this validate function.:

[image]

[this is Complete code](https://github.com/flashliu/NestServer)

sorry, my English is bad, this is my first-time use stackoverflow, thanks for your help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `validate` method of your `JwtStrategy` will only be called when the token has been verified in terms of the encryption (corrrect key was used to sign it, in your case `secretKey`) and it is not expired. Only after those two things have been checked, `validate` is called with the payload. With it, you can then e.g. check if the user still exists. So the three steps are:

1. Token was signed with your secret key
2. Token is not expired
3. Custom payload validation

You can use the [jwt debugger](https://jwt.io/) to manually check steps 1 and 2 for your token.

Comment: Thank you, I find the reason,at here"ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')", “jwt” is lower case，but  "JWT" is capital in header Authorization , This is a silly mistake.

Comment: Yeah, it's always the silly little things that take hours to solve. Glad it's working now. :) And welcome to stackoverflow! :)

Comment: How could you intercept these failures? I want to return a custom error message?

Answer (score 1):

I would also add my scenario.
**Case 1: JWT token is malformed**
Basically, when your JWT token is **malformed (don't confuse with not valid)** the **validate** function would **NOT** call. In other words, when you debug token via jwt.io and it shows signature is not valid.
It appears from my side even if I was login in succesfully on local via
`@auth0/auth0-angular`, I was not providing **audience** url(available on APIs section in auth0). The getting started docs was not mentioning this, so below is working code

```
   // Angular side

    AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: `${auth.domain}`,
      clientId: 'client-id',
      useRefreshTokens: true,
      audience: `https://${auth.audience}/`
    }),
```

**Case 2: JWT token is not valid**

In that case, I found out that URLs provided in JwtStrategy in NestJs, the URLs must be an exact match. So if you forget to add `/` at the end of the URL, it would not pass `AuthGuard`.

```
// NestJs side

export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `https://${auth.domain}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: `https://${auth.audience}/`,
      issuer: `https://${auth.domain}}/`,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  public validate(payload: any): unknown {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

Comment: `So if you forget to add / at the end of the URL, it would not pass AuthGuard` This was my problem! Thanks.